# Windows task scheduler - log file C#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have a c# program that has app.config. I have

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="logFile" value="Logs.txt"/>
  </appSettings>


namespace LogTesting
{
    class LogMessages
    {
        public static string WriteToFile(string Exceptionfrom, string text)
        {
            var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Program.destnDirectoryName);
            if (!dir.Exists) dir.Create();
            var path = Path.Combine(dir.FullName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFile"]);

            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFile"]))
            {
                Log(Exceptionfrom, text, w);
            }
            return path;
        }

        public static void Log(string Exceptionfrom, string logMessage, TextWriter w)
        {
            w.WriteLine("{0}\t{1} ", Exceptionfrom, logMessage);

        }
    }
}


using LogTesting;
namespace MainProgram
{
       class Program
    {
        public const string destnDirectoryName = @"C:\tempLogs";
[STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
LogMessages.WriteFile("in main", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
}
}
```

When I run this F5 or CTRL+F5, log gets written to C:\tempLogs\Logs.txt. When I put this in windows task scheduler, log does not get written . Why is it?

Thanks
R

Comment: With which credentials is the task running, if different from the credentials running your Visual Studio instance ? I would recommend you use a try/catch block and see if you get any errors while running it as a task.

Comment: Check to see that the user your submitting the job under has permissions to create/write to that folder.